# Using `continue` keywoard in a switch nest inside a foreach loop

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, switch-statement, continue

I have the code below (which actually is much longer than you see!)

```
foreach (SensorPair sensor in _sensorPairs)
{
    sensorByte = (byte) sensor.Sensor;

    if (!packet.Contains(sensorByte))
        continue;

    index = packet.IndexOf(sensorByte);
    byteCount = sensor.ByteCount;

    switch (byteCount)
    {
        case 1:
            try
            {
                switch(sensor.ValueType)
                {
                    case SensorValueType.Unsigned:
                        val = (int)packet[index + 1];
                        if (val > 255)
                            //*** WHAT DOES THIS CONTINUE DO?
                            continue;   
                        else //rise the event
                           OnSensorReport();                              
                    break;
```

Does the `continue`keywoard you see cause the foreach loop to start itterating next item or it just passes to the next `case` statement?

If it does not do anything with the foreach loop, how can I force the code to exit the switch and starts the next itteration in the foreach loop?

Comment: It [`continue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)s (or skips to the next iteration) of the current `foreach` loop.

Comment: -1, when you tested it, what happened?

Comment: It continues the loop. Going to the next case is "goto Case 2;".

Comment: Thanks for negatives I really needed that :D

Comment: I have a congruent control structure (loop with try/catch containing `switch`). A `break` skips to the end of the `switch`, a `continue` skips to the next iteration, and an exception triggers the exception handling and goes on to the next iteration. [Here is an MCVE](http://ideone.com/fBm7sW) for as long as ideONE keeps it.

Comment: In [this msdn docu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) you can see that there is no fall through in C#: "Unlike C++, C# does not allow execution to continue from one switch section to the next. The following code causes an error."

Comment: Just thought I'd say that I appreciate this question/post because it helped explain my code. I have a switch statement inside a do..while loop and for fun I added a `continue` instead of a `break` to my surprise the `continue` didn't error and it "broke" the switch statement. It's only after reading this SO post I realize that it broke the do..while loop, thus indirectly breaking the switch statement. The switch statement is the last thing in the loop, so I never would have known what was really happening in my code if it wasn't for this SO post.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, it continues the `foreach` loop.

It is always useful to consult the [**documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/923ahwt1.aspx) ;-)

> The continue statement passes control to the next iteration of the
>   enclosing while, do, for, or foreach statement in which it appears.

or—more comprehensive—the [**C# language specification**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228593.aspx):

**8.9.2 The continue statement**

> The continue statement starts a new iteration of the **nearest enclosing
>   while, do, for, or foreach statement**.
>
> The target of a continue statement is the end point of the embedded
>   statement of the nearest enclosing while, do, for, or foreach
>   statement. If a continue statement is not enclosed by a while, do,
>   for, or foreach statement, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> When multiple while, do, for, or foreach statements are nested within
>   each other, a continue statement applies **only to the innermost
>   statement**. To transfer control across multiple nesting levels, a goto
>   statement (§8.9.3) must be used.
>
> A continue statement cannot exit a finally block (§8.10). When a
>   continue statement occurs within a finally block, the target of the
>   continue statement must be within the same finally block; otherwise a
>   compile-time error occurs.
>
> A continue statement is executed as follows:
>
> - If the continue statement exits one or more try blocks with
>     associated finally blocks, control is initially transferred to the
>     finally block of the innermost try statement. When and if control
>     reaches the end point of a finally block, control is transferred to
>     the finally block of the next enclosing try statement. This process is
>     repeated until the finally blocks of all intervening try statements
>     have been executed.
> - Control is transferred to the target of the continue
>     statement.
>
> Because a continue statement unconditionally transfers control
>   elsewhere, the end point of a continue statement is never reachable.